# How to configure CI/CD for Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine, cicd

I'm just starting my first steps on the subject and I need help please. My application runs with Docker. I have a Azure Virtual Machine also with Docker installed, and the source code repository in DevOps. It is taking me a while to configure the CI/CD to deploy my application.

Comment: Hi there, Glad to know the issue is resolved from your side and you consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to help others with similar concerns. Thanks a lot for the efforts!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*I'm creating again and answering my own question because when I created it another time, it turned out to be "too big, and no one was going to give me a 10-page answer." Now after a lot of effort I achieved the goal and I want to share the knowledge acquired.*

What I did was:

- Connect to my VM using ssh.
- Configure ssh on the VM and in DevOps, to be able to clone the repo using ssh from the VM (empty passphrases).
- Clone the repo to the VM using ssh.
- Add a self-hosted build agent to my VM and register it on my Azure DevOps project (Thanks to Mr. @Shamrai, check his answer for more info).
- Create an Environment in DevOps to be able to point to my VM in the Pipeline.
- Create the Pipeline

Pipeline:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- deployment: VMDeploy
  displayName: Deploy to VM
  environment:
   name: VM-ENV
   resourceName: VM
   resourceType: virtualMachine
  strategy:
     runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
            clean: true
            persistCredentials: true
          - script: git -C ~/Dir/to/repo pull
          - script: docker compose -f ~/Dir/to/repo/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

I hope it is helpful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

You must add a self-hosted build agent to your VM and register it on your Azure DevOps project: [Self-hosted Linux agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux-agent?view=azure-devops). Then you may run your pipelines on the VM (use the correct pool value). Here you may find a similar question: [Create docker image using azure build pipeline, self-hosted agent and docker-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75590382/create-docker-image-using-azure-build-pipeline-self-hosted-agent-and-docker-des)

Comment: You are right sir, I also had to do that step and I completely forgot about it. Thank you. I can add it in my answer with your permission.

Comment: @ldiaz997 pls add, maybe someone also will have the same issue